# How to find Vendor ID and Product ID of Sim900a

Tags: linux, simcom

I have been trying to get my Sim900a detected on my Ubuntu. In order to follow the instructions of SIMCom [here](https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM5360/How%20to%20use%20linux%20driver.pdf) and [here](https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM5300x/SIM5300E_Linux_driver_Application%20Note_V1.00.pdf), I need its vendor ID and product ID to be put into `option.c` in the kernel.
I checked the [hardware manual](https://www.datasheet-pdf.info/attach/1/3304130011.pdf) but could not find any mention of the two IDs.

Torvalds' `option.c` does mention SIMCom devices and their IDs but not Sim900a.
As such my modem-manager is unable to detect the modem when I connect it through a USB-Serial interface.
Its been almost a month and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does lsusb return with the device plugged in?

Comment: Also that manual is from 2008 and the makeconfig shows kernel version 2.6 - in dog years that’s old and in computer years that’s older than god. There may be more modern ways of using this device.

Comment: lsusb gives:
```Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b00a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:706e Lite-On Technology Corp. HP HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 0403:6001 FTDI USB Serial Device converter
```

Comment: Sim900a works fine on Windows using an MCU and Arduino IDE. AT commands gives OK. I want it to work on Ubuntu which I mainly use.

Comment: unplug the module from the  computer and  lsusb again. dont paste the result - instead compare the new list with the list when it's plugged in. I suspect that the module is going to be the FTDI usb serial, in which case it already works fine and simply needs a terminal fired up. also if it works in windows fire up device manager, right clikc the device and select properties (https://kb.synology.com/en-uk/DSM/tutorial/How_do_I_check_the_PID_VID_of_my_USB_device)

Comment: In both Ubuntu (lsusb) and Windows (Device Manager) only the FTDI chip is recognized automatically and not SIm900a.

Comment: It seems to me the ftdi is embedded in your sim900 kit you’re using and provides serial access. Under Linux these will commonly mount as /dev/ttyUSB0 (or 1 or 2 etc).

Comment: No they are separate. I connect to the USB-to-Serial converter (having an FTDI chip) to Sim900a through Tx and Rx. Then USB-to-Serial converter is put in the laptop. 
In Windows I connect Sim900a through MCU to USB port and AT commands work just fine there.